Elementor Toggle Button Not Displaying Correctly on Mobile Devices
I am encountering an issue with Elementor on my WordPress site. The toggle button (used for mobile navigation) appears correctly in the Elementor mobile responsive preview, but on an actual mobile device, it only shows a white dot. When I click this dot, it displays the menu options correctly.
Check the solution given by chatbot
Ensured Elementor is Updated: Both Elementor and Elementor Pro are updated to the latest versions.
Checked for Plugin Conflicts: Deactivated all plugins except Elementor and Elementor Pro. The issue persists even with all other plugins deactivated.
Switched to a Default Theme: Switched to the Twenty Twenty-One theme. The issue still persists with the default theme.
Cleared Cache: Cleared the browser cache and site cache (including server-side cache).Used Safe Mode in Elementor:
Enabled Safe Mode to disable all other plugins and switch to a default theme temporarily. The issue still occurs in Safe Mode.
